# Find limit of $n x_n$ knowing limit of $n^2 (x_{n+1}-x_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

My friend gave me this sequence problem:

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2(x_{n+1} - x_n) = L$, then what is $\lim_{n \to \infty} nx_n$?

I think Cesaro-Stolz theorem can be used , but is there another way?

Comment: Can $L$ be infinite?

Comment: Yes I mean $L$ is a finite real number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ such that for all $k \geqslant N$ we have when $L$ is finite

$$L- \epsilon < k^2(x_{k+1} - x_k) < L + \epsilon$$

Summing from $k=n$ to $m$ and multiplying by $n$ we get

$$(L - \epsilon)n\sum_{k=n}^m \frac{1}{k^2} < nx_{m+1} - nx_n < (L + \epsilon)n\sum_{k=n}^m \frac{1}{k^2} $$

By hypothesis $x_{m+1} \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$ and it follows that

$$(L - \epsilon)n\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \leqslant - nx_n \leqslant (L + \epsilon)n\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} $$

Since $n\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \sim 1$, we get for any $\epsilon > 0$

$$L- \epsilon \leqslant \liminf(-nx_n) \leqslant \limsup (-nx_n) \leqslant L + \epsilon$$

Thus, $n x_n \to -L$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Nice, how do you show $n \sum_n^\infty (1/k^2) \sim 1$?

Comment: Euler-Maclaurin or since $1/x^2$ is decreasing we have $\int_{n}^\infty x^{-2} \, dx < \sum_{k=n}^\infty k^{-2} < \int_{n-1}^\infty x^{-2} \, dx$. This gives $1 <  n\sum_{k=n}^\infty k^{-2} < n/(n-1)$.